# Как правильно создать доп. процесс в серверном приложении?

Tags: winapi, c++

Добрый день.

Можете посоветовать аналог fork для Windows? Пишу простенький сервер, раньше не приходилось сталкиваться с созданием процессов в windows, создавал процессы в linux... Было просто:

`fork(); if(fork==0)`- дочерний процесс.

А в виндовс  нашел

`CreateProcess(commandline, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)`,

почитал документацию, так и не понял как можно обмениваться переменными(информацией) с созданным процессом. Вообще, его даже созданным не назвал бы, скорее запущенным... Кто-нибудь создавал подобного рода серверы?

Comment: `CreateProcess` + пайпы. Если хочется живых примеров, то посмотрите, как написан [`googletest`](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/).

Comment: В СССР секса нет. Пардон, в виндах форка нет (исключение -- различные библиотеки эмуляции POSIX, но надо учитывать, что коровы (cow -- copy on write) там не используются, потому тормоза. Само порождение процесса под виндами операция нешустрая по причине системы безопасности. Используйте нити/потоки -- CreateThread.

Comment: Но если хотите убедиться на собственном опыте -- поставьте cygwin (www.cygwin.com). Там fork есть, хотя он и эмулируется с помощью нитей. И select есть (не только для сокетов, как в win32api). И тоже эмулируется с помощью нитей. Только не удивляйтесь, что по скорости эти операции не сравнимы с линуксовыми.

Comment: Выходит можно в visual studio написать fork(), cygwing его преобразует и всё будет работать в Windows? Я правильно вас понял?

Comment: Насчёт visual studio -- это вряд ли. Я не настолько хорошо знаю ms vs, чтобы описать, как в ней собирать программы под cygwin. Главная часть cygwin -- библиотека cygwin1.dll, реализующая posix-вызовы посредством вызовов win32api (иногда эти действия получаются сильно нетривиальными, см. fork, select). Вызовы win32api из программы разрешены. Компиляторы -- gcc/g++ поставляются (выбираются) в установщике cygwin (вроде setup.exe)

Comment: CreateProcess - это скорее system/exec... С точки зрения серверных приложений под виндой традиционно используется multi-Thread - попробуйте - это весьма мощный инструмент.