# Аналог fork() для Windows

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Очевидно что `fork()` не имплементирован в Windows API, и все что есть, это варианты вокруг `CreateProccess`, как например в cygwin.

Вопрос, с какими ключами и параметрами надо запускать `CreateProccess` что бы безболезненно выйти из первого процесса и освободить консоль?

И я так понимаю что заставить код выполняться с того же места откуда вызван `CreateProccess` реально нет никакой возможности ? и надо придумывать костыли с обнаружением был или не был уже первый форк. Какие есть решения по этому поводу?

Желаемое поведение:
1. Родительский процесс запускает дочерний и сам завершаеться.
2. Работает только бывшый дочерний процесс.
3. Задача освободить консоль и выполняться в "фоне".

Как в случае отделенного дочернего процесса обстоят дела с вводом/выводом в Вин, с учётом закрытия парента..

Comment: Дубль https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/193525

Comment: Посмотрел, но ответа там не обнаружил, интересует более вторая часть вопроса, про место старта кода, если можно так выразиться. Общие рассуждения на эту тему известны. Нити в задаче освободить консоль не подходят.

Comment: уточните, какое ожидается поведение программы. 1.родительский процесс создает дочерний процесс. 2. родительский процесс останавливается. 3. дочерний процесс выполняется до конца. 4. родительский процесс возобновляется и продолжает выполнение. Такой порядок? А также нужно ли выполнять дочерний процесс в отдельном окне консоли?

Comment: Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: "Освобождение консоли" (точнее смена control tty) не происходит в обычном `fork`. Для такого поведения в новом процессе еще вызывают [setsid](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setsid)

Comment: Да, конечно, но это в posix, тут речь идёт о виндовс, тут все малость по другому :) но задача то тривиальная на мой взгляд, освободить консоль.. может есть иные пути решения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем в черновом варианте мультиплатформный форк получился следующим образом:
Отлов состояния в Вин версии происходит по ключам командной строки.

Одно не ясно, как быть в таком случае с очисткой хендлов от CreateProccess,
типовая очистка/закрытие вроде так:

```
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```

но я сильно опасаюсь что это убьет/испортит инстанцию которую создает CreateProccess..

код:

```
int my_fork(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#   if defined(OS_WIN)

    int i, ret = 0;
    size_t sz = 0;
    char *cmd = NULL;
    char *p;

    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        size_t ssz;

        if (!argv[i])
            break;

        ssz = strlen(argv[i]);

        if (
            (
                (ssz == 2U) &&
                (!memcmp(argv[i], (void*)&"-k", 2U))
            )
            ||
            (
                (ssz == 9U) &&
                (!memcmp(argv[i], (void*)&"--nonloop", 9U))
            )
        )
            continue;

        if (!(p = realloc(cmd, (size_t)(sz + ssz + 2U))))
        {
            if (cmd)
                free(cmd);
            return -1;
        }

        cmd = p;
        memcpy((void*)(p + sz), argv[i], ssz);
        sz += ssz;
        p[sz] = 0x20;
        p[++sz] = 0x0;
    }

    sz = ((sz) ? (sz - 1) : 0);

    if ((!cmd) || (!sz))
    {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    /* remove last blank 0x20 */
    cmd[sz] = 0x0;

    do
    {
        STARTUPINFO si;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

        memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
        memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));
        si.cb = sizeof(si);
        si.dwFlags |= DETACHED_PROCESS;

        if (!CreateProcess(
                    NULL,
                    cmd,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    FALSE,
                    CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT | DETACHED_PROCESS,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    &si,
                    &pi
                )
           )
        {
            ret = -((int)GetLastError());
        }
    }
    while (0);

    free(cmd);
    return ret;

#   elif defined(__GNUC__)

    (void) argc;
    (void) argv;

    switch(fork())
    {
    case 0:
    {
        int cfd;
        (void) signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);

        if ((cfd = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR, 0)) >= 0)
        {
            dup2(cfd, STDIN_FILENO);
            dup2(cfd, STDOUT_FILENO);
            dup2(cfd, STDERR_FILENO);

            if (cfd > 2)
            {
                close(cfd);
            }
        }
        if ((getppid() != 1) && (setsid() < 0))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        (void) sleep(12);
        return (int)getpid();
    }
    case -1:
    {
        return -1;
    }
    default:
    {
        (void) signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
        errno = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    }
#   else
    /* default value > 0, continue run, no errors */
    return 100;
#   endif
}
```

UPD. если в дальнейшем вызывать `CreateProccess`, то для предотвращения моргания новыми окнами необходимо указывать флаг `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`.

да, для понимания, запускается оно примерно так:

```
    switch(my_fork(argc, argv))
    {
    case -1:
    {
        exit(127);
    }
    case 0:
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    default:
    {
        break;
    }
    }
```

Comment: "_но я сильно опасаюсь что это убьет/испортит инстанцию которую создает CreateProccess_" - не убьет и не испортит.

Comment: @freim, Да, спасибо, я уже проверил, это было давненько.. :)

Comment: почему пропускаются `-k` и `--nonloop` ?

Answer (score 1):

Я не очень знаком с Юниксом вообще и функцией `fork` в частности, но если я правильно помню, поддержка волокон (fibers) в Windows как раз и была введена для портирования приложений Unix, использующих `fork`. Суть там в том, что в понимании Windows программа с `fork` является однопоточной, и реализация ее через механизм многопоточности очень неудобна. Поэтому в Windows NT и появились волокна. Используются они редко (потому что потоки лучше) и про них мало кто помнит, но к вашей задаче они подойдут идеально - для этого их и придумали.

Документация по волокнам [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/fibers). Еще они описаны в классической книге Джеффри Рихтера "Windows для профессионалов", приложение А.